# Error at PlanetMath? (lattice theory: pseudocomplement)

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ is a lattice.

At [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/pseudocomplement) it's written:

> It is easy to see that given an element $a\in L$, the pseudocomplement of $a$, if it exists, is unique.

Is it true in general? I see a proof only for special classes of lattices, such as distributive lattice. Is it an error in PlanetMath or I just miss a proof for the general case?

Answer (score 5):

This follows directly from the properties of the pseudocomplement given above the quoted sentence. If $b$ and $b'$ are pseudocomplements of an element $a$, then property 1 says that $b\land a=0$ and $b'\land a=0$. Then property 2 of $b$ implies $b'\le b$, and property 2 of $b'$ implies $b\le b'$. This implies $b=b'$ by the antisymmetry of the partial order $\le$.

Comment: It seems that in PlanetMath "maximum of a set" and "greatest element of a set" are confused. See http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj;from=objects;id=2749

Comment: @porton: Strange, I can't find the word "maximum" on either page -- where did you find it?

Comment: Search "maximal element" at http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/Benzene.html

Comment: @porton: How am I going to find "maximum of a set" by searching for "maximal element"? Or are you saying that your first comment was in error and you meant "maximal element"?

Comment: "Maximum of a set" and "greatest element of a set" are both defined at http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj;from=objects;id=2749 - it seems these are confused in the definition of co-brouwerian lattice. We must find THE CORRECT definition of co-brouwerian lattices.

Comment: @porton: I'm getting more and more confused. Why are you talking about "maximum of a set"? I asked where you found this expression on these pages, but you pointed me to "maximal element" instead. What's the relevance of the definition of a term that doesn't appear anywhere on the pages in question?

Comment: Are you telling about a distinction between "maximum of a set" and "maximal element"? Isn't "maximal element" of a set the same as maximum of this set? If these are not the same, then the confused person is me. I was sure these two are the same.

Comment: Yes, I was confused: maximum and maximal elements are not the same: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element

Comment: "Maximum" and "maximal element" are not the same. This was the reason of confusion.